# Populate VBA Object with HPC

Tags: object, hpc

We are looking into HPC for improving processing on some of our larger, more complex spreadsheets. We have demo'd this to some colleagues and the area they can see this being useful is with a spreadsheet tool that, as part of the calculation routine, generates a 5-dimensional array (each dimension about 100 rows by 100 columns) to be used in later calculations. They asked if it was possible to use HPC to share the calculation load of this object rather than write the results back to cells?
I've done some searches but am unable to find anything that covers this...does this mean it can't be done, or just that it's not really how HPC is intended for use?

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to Microsoft HPC 2012 or 2008 R2, it can be used to do quite a number of things from processing raw unstructured data to doing excel calculations.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853440(v=vs.85).aspx

That link is for the 2008 R2 documentation (no new samples for 2012 have been published) one of the samples is a spreadsheet that has its values calculated via HPC.  You want to look at the MonteCarloCLI example if memory serves from the Excel directory in the SP4 sample pack.